# How do I block all internet connections but permit connections within localhost?

Tags: firewall

I'm testing a program I built regarding its ethernet/internet behaviour. It's a server/client application. I need to block the server's internet connection while the client still has access to the internet (but I'm running both in the same machine, for testing, trying to simulate what will happen when I get this into the proper hardware). Although the server must not have access to the internet, server and client must still communicate with the localhost address for database communication. VMs are not an option as of now, although they could be perfect.

The problem is that if I try to block internet connections in my firewall for the server process, I also block it from communicating with the client running in the same PC (trying to access it via localhost:port). Ideally, the server would be completely isolated, EXCEPT for local comms with the client program.

How do I properly block ONLY internet connections?